# Testing a static variable

Tags: c, validation, unit-testing, testing, verification

I am trying to unit test a function that uses a static 32 bit unsigned integer.

The function under test will increment the unsigned integer by one.

So, it is essentially:

```
void IncrementCount() {
    Spi_count++;
}
```

When the `Spi_Count` variable is tested by giving input as maximum value i.e 0xFFFFFFFF
then if I expect 0x100000000 as output the test passes.  If I expect 0 as output then it also passes.

How can the unsigned variable pass the test for both the values 0 and 0x100000000?

Comment: What language are you working in? Also, it's usually helpful to show a concise code sample the correctly compiles and reproduces what you are talking about.

Comment: In c, funtion() { Spi_count++;}

Comment: I edited your question and the tag for C. Typically you'd want to edit your question in response to a comment like mine. You might want to improve your title (it doesn't tell me *what* you are trying to test).

Comment: We're going to need to see more code than what you've provided. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question to show us how you are testing it, how you declaring the variable, and how you are incrementing it.

Answer (score 1):

`0x100000000` isn't a 32 bit number.  32 bits is 4 bytes, or 8 hex digits.  You are attempting to check 5 bytes (0x1 00 00 00 00), rather than 4.  Without your code, it's impossible to say for certain but the likelihood is that the compiler is using the lower 4 bytes in the comparison which evaluate to 0, hence your test working.

[Simple coding example to reproduce the problem](http://ideone.com/UQICfg).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    unsigned int cX=-1;

    printf("%04X\n", cX);
    cX++;
    printf("%04X\n", cX);

    // Doing an explicit test of the unsigned int to 0x100000000 evaluates to false, as expected
    printf("%d\n", cX==0x1000000);                 // Outputs 0 (false)

    // If you cast the right side down to an unsigned int, then the high order bytes are lost
    // and you are essentially comparing against 0, so the comparison is a success
    printf("%d\n", cX==(unsigned)0x100000000);     // Outputs 1 (true)


    // You can do the same thing by accident using a hidden cast by calling a function.  Both
    // parameters are cast down to unsigned ints for the call so the right hand side loses its
    // most significant bytes, resulting in 0 again.
    printf("%d\n", compare(cX, 0x100000000));     // Outputs 1 (true)


    return 0;
}

int compare(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return x==y;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the program outputs, how?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you cast an unsigned 64 bit number (0x100000000) to an unsigned 32 bit number, either either explicitly through `(unsigned)0x100000000` or through a function call, you throw away the top 32 bits.  If you remove the top 32 bits from 0x100000000, you get 0.  The 1 is in the 33rd bit, so doesn't make it through the casting.

Comment: Sir, the unsigned 32 bit integer is a global variable, the function will increment the variable by 1 each time when the function is called. I need to check whether the function increment the value of the variable by 1 or not using a testing tool through which I provide input values for the variable and expect the output value, when I give input 0xFFFFFFFF and expect 0x100000000, whether the testing tool itself is taking expected value 0x100000000 as 0 and then it is comparing with the obtained value from the code which is 0, and hence it is accepting both the expected values 0 and 0x100000000?

Comment: The actual expected value is 0.  There is no point trying to test for 0x100000000 since it can't possibly be held in a 32 bit number.  The test itself makes no sense.  If your test tool has a 64 bit unsigned comparison method then it would probably work as your expecting and error, however the test would still be meaningless in the real world.